# Querying Embedded array fields in a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb databse, am having problem trying to query a field. My collection users looks like this:

```
{

"_id" : "sam",
"_password" : "t",
"data" : [
    {
        "_id" : "hp",
        "nodeList" : [{'nodeId' : 1},{'nodeId' : 2},{'nodeId' : 3}],
        "edgeList" : [{'edgeId' : 1},{'edgeId' : 2},{'edgeId' : 3}],
        "options" : {
            "edgeColor" : "blue",
            "nodeColor" : "black"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : "tt",
        "nodeList" : [{'nodeId' : 1},{'nodeId' : 2},{'nodeId' : 3}],
        "edgeList" : [{'edgeId' : 1},{'edgeId' : 2},{'edgeId' : 3}],
        "options" : {
            "edgeColor" : "blue",
            "nodeColor" : "black"
        }
    }
]}, 

{

"_id" : "bob",
"_password" : "w",
"data" : [
    {
        "_id" : "hello",
        "nodeList" : [{'nodeId' : 1},{'nodeId' : 2},{'nodeId' : 3}],
        "edgeList" : [{'edgeId' : 1},{'edgeId' : 2},{'edgeId' : 3}],
        "options" : {
            "edgeColor" : "blue",
            "nodeColor" : "black"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : "world",
        "nodeList" : [{'nodeId' : 1},{'nodeId' : 2},{'nodeId' : 3}],
        "edgeList" : [{'edgeId' : 1},{'edgeId' : 2},{'edgeId' : 3}],
        "options" : {
            "edgeColor" : "blue",
            "nodeColor" : "black"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I need to retrieve the `nodeList/edgeLis`t from this and also change the edgeColor in options given a particular `_id`. For eg : `_ id : "bob"`.

I tried a few things but could not get the output.

```
db.users.find({ '_id': 'sam' , "users.data._id" : "hp"}, {})
db.users.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":"sam", "users.data._id": "hp"},{$addToSet:{"users.data.nodeList":{"nodeId":1,"nodeName":"Bellanduru", "lat":43.12, "long":33.43,"stock":3}}})
```

Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Don't think this is doable in a single query. You will have to get the inner node document object in the data array and set the value on it, then set it on the user document, then run your update query with the updated user document. One thing that I noticed was incorrect in your query is prefixing "users." to your keys. You don't have to do this as you already adrressing the users collection when you type "db.users...."

Answer (score 0):

you declare your collection name with this `db.users` in  selected db

and you select `users`  collection so not necessary specify in query

for example this `"users.data._id"` replace with this `"data._id"`

replace your querys like this

```
db.users.find({ '_id': 'sam' , "data._id" : "hp"}, {})
db.users.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":"sam", "data._id": "hp"},{$addToSet:{"data.nodeList":{"nodeId":1,"nodeName":"Bellanduru", "lat":43.12, "long":33.43,"stock":3}}})
```